Screen scrape with beautifulsoup from yahoo finance works for all stocks except one
I have tried for days to solve this problem but have run out of ideas. I am using Python3 and Beautifulsoup to scrape a stock price from Yahoo Finance. It works fine for a hundred or so different stocks that I have tried so far except 1 and that is Rolls Royce RR.L. The HTML looks the same as any other stock but it won't retrieve any data let alone the price.
This is the code that I have used. I change the stock symbol on line 3 to suit. I have also experimented with several User Agents but it makes no difference and I am not so sure that it would as I am only making a query 2 or 3 times per day. Could it possibly be anything to do with the '.' in the stock symbol?
Many thanks for any suggestion
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/RR.L'
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
# Find the price in the page
price_tag = soup.find('fin-streamer' ,{'data-field': 'regularMarketPrice'})
print(price_tag)

I have tried to alter the soup.find command but am really only guessing.

I'm not sure why, but it's returning JavaScript that displays the message Content is currently unavailable

It also has a redirect to https://brb.yahoo.net/finance.yahoo.com/desktop/quote/RR.L/index.html which displays a "We'll be right back" message, as if the site is down for maintenance.

When I get via postman I see: "Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue."

Thanks for your input. Interesting responses about being unavailable etc. I am not sure where I would even find those. It has been this way since I first tried it over a week ago.

Well, Yahoo Finance goes for maintenance often so you can try this API endpoint to check if it's available or not, which will also print your desired output,
Sample code:
import requests

url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/RR.L'
header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:131.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/131.0"
}
resp = requests.get(url, headers=header).json()['chart']['result'][0]['meta']['regularMarketPrice']

print(resp)

Output:
538.8

