Python requests error processing YahooFinance URL with dot in it
I would like to show you this random issue with a parsing script i wrote for Yahoo Finance stocks pages.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers ={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

symbol = "AAPL"
symbol1 = 'UST.MI'

url_template = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+symbol
url_template1 = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+symbol1

r = requests.get(url_template, headers=headers)
r1 = requests.get(url_template1, headers=headers)

Now, as you can imagine :

r => <Response [200]>
r1 => <Response [404]>

Other tickers (i.e. GOOG) gives also response 200.
It seems the problem is when a ticker symbol has a dot in it (i.e. UST.MI).
Also, the issue seems to be random (not all days, not always, but now it's like a week of no working).
Anyone came across this issue, or know how to deal with it?
and: how to check if yahoo is blocking some traffic, since the issue seems to be random?
Thank you very much ;-)

import from urllib.parse import quote and try quote("UST.MI"). dot character is allowed in urls, but sometimes it can cause issues when used in HTTP requests. You can also take a look at https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/

i tried, no effect. also, i do believe dots do not need to be escaped or quoted. thanks for the link, but i would like to build my script and learning something in doing so ;-)

potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79163931/screen-scrape-with-beautifulsoup-from-yahoo-finance-works-for-all-stocks-except

Yahoo Finance requires certain HTTP headers for near-reliable behaviour.
Why some symbols can be accessed without these headers is a mystery (to me).
However, the following works for both of the symbols you're interested in:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

try:
    import lxml
    PARSER = "lxml"
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    PARSER = "html.parser"

URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"

with requests.Session() as session:
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.3",
        "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br, zstd",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"
    }
    session.headers.update(headers)
    for symbol in "GOOG", "UST.MI":
        try:
            with session.get(URL+symbol) as response:
                response.raise_for_status()
                soup = BS(response.text, PARSER)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


still not working. maybe yahoo is filtering traffic from italy ? or something like that? but why only for that stock lol it is driving me crazy

@DavideFagioli If you think it might be due to your locale, try a VPN
